# Want to daemonize django-gevent server

Tags: python, django, gevent, django-wsgi, python-daemon

In my project, I had replaced the django-development server with gevent using monkey patch and its working perfectly, So now my manage.py file look like-

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler as DjangoWSGIApp
application = DjangoWSGIApp()
server = WSGIServer(("192.168.0.14", 8080), application)
try:
 print "Starting Green server on http://192.168.0.14:8000"
 server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
 server.stop()
 print "server has stopped by Admin"
```

So this is working fine for me, when i am running it normally. And then i tried to host this on our private cloud, for that i used three  instances one for `openid provider` and another one as an `openid consumer`, and one for `mongodb`, there also it was working as expected, but i was facing some `cross domain` problems so i am using `proxy` now to resolve that.

PROBLEM-

1- With cloud instance

Then i tried to daemonize the script using (`python manage.py &`) so that i can close the ssh connection to my instance, After daemonizing i was able to use the first instance but whenever i am trying for login or logout ,i am getting `I/O error`.

2- On Development PC

After daemonizing, when `i tried to access the url, it wasn't connecting`, but when i checked the processess using "ps aux | grep manage.py", the script was running there.

I think i am missing something while daemonizing this script. i used the `python daemon` library but that was also not working.

Comment: For daemonizing, try this instead of the python daemon library:     http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/